# The R plot_ly stacked bar chart can only show multiple values with different colors

Tags: r, plotly, stacked-bar-chart

I am programming a R-application, where I need to visualize data in stacked bar-charts. So far everything works fine if there are multiple bars shown, but I am getting empty graphs when I want to show only one bar.

So I created different plots with some dummy data, that shows my problem. (The data is fictitious)

```
data <- data.table(FRUIT = c("apples", "bananas", "kiwis", "apples", "bananas", "kiwis"), 
                    KCALS = c(100, 200, 130, 100, 200, 130), 
                    DATE = as.Date(c("2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-10-02", "2022-10-03", "2022-10-03")))
```

[image: dummy-data]

The first graph shows an overview over multiple dates:

```
plot_ly(data, x = ~DATE, y = ~KCALS, color = ~FRUIT, type = "bar") %>%
    layout(yaxis = list(title = " "), xaxis = list(title = " "), barmode = "stack")
```

[image]

The second graph shows only one day:

```
plot_ly(data[DATE == "2022-10-01"], x = ~DATE, y = ~KCALS, type = "bar") %>%
    layout(yaxis = list(title = " "), xaxis = list(title = " "), barmode = "stack")
```

[image]

Ok, that worked. But if I enable the "color-option" again, the plot is empty:

```
plot_ly(data[DATE == "2022-10-01"], x = ~DATE, y = ~KCALS, color = ~FRUIT, type = "bar") %>%
    layout(yaxis = list(title = " "), xaxis = list(title = " "), barmode = "stack")
```

[image]

Why is it behaving like this? What am I doing wrong? And is there any documentation available, that really describes how the data gets processed in the `plot_ly()`- function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your code with `color` variable it does return a stacked bar plot  for a single value. Make sure you don't overwrite variables and try it with a clean environment. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(FRUIT = c("apples", "bananas", "kiwis", "apples", "bananas", "kiwis"), 
                   KCALS = c(100, 200, 130, 100, 200, 130), 
                   DATE = as.Date(c("2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-10-02", "2022-10-03", "2022-10-03")))
library(plotly)
plot_ly(data, x = ~DATE, y = ~KCALS, color = ~FRUIT, type = "bar") %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = " "), xaxis = list(title = " "), barmode = "stack")
```

[image]

```r
plot_ly(data[DATE == "2022-10-01"], x = ~DATE, y = ~KCALS, type = "bar") %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = " "), xaxis = list(title = " "), barmode = "stack")
```

[image]

```r
plot_ly(data[DATE == "2022-10-01"], x = ~DATE, y = ~KCALS, color = ~FRUIT, type = "bar") %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = " "), xaxis = list(title = " "), barmode = "stack")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Here you can find the [docs](https://plotly.com/r/bar-charts/) about bar charts in `plotly`.

Comment: Hmm, I tried what you said and it worked. I was creating the plots in a jupyter-notebook-file, because it was easier to maintance them there. New learning: the problem only appears in a jupyter-notebook. Thanks for your help.